# Last 2 numbers of the product of divisors

Tags: number-theory

> Let $N$ be the product of all divisors of $2013^{2013}$. What are the
>   last 2 numbers of $N$ in its decimal notation?

I don't know where to start in this exercise, would like to get a hint or two :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that the product of all divisors of an integer $n$ is $\sqrt{n^{\tau(n)}}$, where $\tau(n)$ denotes the number of divisors of $n$. Since $2013=3\cdot11\cdot61$, we see that

$$\tau(2013^{2013})=\tau(3^{2013})\tau(11^{2013})\tau(61^{2013})=2014^3$$

Moreover, as $\textbf{Ivan Loh}$ pointed out, Euler's totient theorem tells us that $a^{\varphi(100)}=a^{40}\equiv_{100}1$ for $\gcd(a,100)=1$. It follows that

$\begin{align*}N&=\sqrt{(2013^{2013})^{\tau\left(2013^{2013}\right)}}=2013^{2013(1007)(2014)^2}\equiv_{100}13^{13(7)(14)^2}=\\&=13^{91(196)}\equiv_{100}13^{11(-4)}\equiv_{100}13^{-4}\equiv_{100}61^{-1}=\left\{a^{-1}=b(ab)^{-1}\right\}=\\&=(1−60)((1+60)(1−60))^{−1}\equiv_{100}-59\equiv_{100}41\end{align*}$

Comment: why did you divide 8169178744 by 2 and how can I tell the mod100 number without calculating the previous one?

Comment: Because $\sqrt{n^{2m}}=n^m$. I will elaborate on the calculations shortly.

Comment: You can show the product of all divisors formula by pairing a divisor $d$ with $\frac n d$ - that picks up each divisor once unless $n$ is a square, and it is easy to adjust for this case. So each pair of complementary divisors contributes $n$ to the product, with an adjustment if necessary for the square root.

Comment: Great thanks for your help! Just wondering if there's a way to do this without a calculator (you had to find those divisors somehow :) )

Comment: @darenn Yes, I admit I used some help with the calculations. However, if necessary, all of this could be done with pen and paper, and some time.

Comment: btw, how do we know the 2 last numbers of mod function?

Comment: You can avoid calculations as follows: We have $\tau(2013^{2013})=2014^3$. Also by Euler's totient theorem (since $\phi(100)=40$), $a^{40} \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$ for $\gcd(a, 100)=1$. Since $2013(1007)(2014)^2 \equiv 13(7)(14)^2 \equiv 91(196) \equiv 11(-4) \equiv -4 \pmod{40}$, so $$N=\sqrt{(2013^{2013})^{\tau(2013^{2013})}}=2013^{2013(1007)(2014)^2} \equiv 13^{-4} \equiv 61^{-1} \equiv 41 \pmod{100}$$ For the last step, you could do $61^{-1} \equiv (1-60)^{-1}((1+60)(1-60))^{-1} \equiv 41 \pmod{100}$.

Comment: @IvanLoh I have replaced the calculations with your observations, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The product of all divisors of N is a multiple of N.